# Confusion with binomial factorization

Tags: polynomials, quadratics, factoring

Say you have the term: $-3x^2+12$ and you want to factor it out:

$$-3(x^2 - 4)$$
$$-3((x+2)(x-2))$$

However you can also write the above as:

$$-3(x+2) (x-2)$$

But in many other cases, e.g if you have $3(4 + 5)$, you can't just turn that into $3(4) + 5$ as you'll get a different result. What's the intuition behind being able to do that in the above example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the above example because $(x+2)$ and $(x-2)$ are multiplied together. If you add them together, notice that
$$-3((x+2)+(x-2))\neq-3(x+2)+(x-2)$$
The general rule is that
$$a(bc)=abc$$
$$a(b+c)=ab+ac$$

Comment: +1 It might be useful to note that the second of the rules has a name: the distributive law - and that factoring is (in a sense) undoing a distributed calculation.